# List of tuples to data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe

looking for ideas on how to solve the problem bellow:

I have a data frame where one of my columns contains a list of tuples like the following:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'Field1' : ['A','B','C'],
        'Field2' : ['1','2','3'],
        'WeirdField' :[ 
                      [ ('xxx', 'F1'), ('yyy','F2') ],
                      [ ('asd', 'F3'), ('bla','F4') ],
                      [ ('123', 'F2'), ('www','F5') ]
                      ]
        })
```

[image]

I would like each element on the second position of the tuple to become a column on the data frame with the corespondent value on the first position.
For the data frame above, this is what I am expecting:

[image]

the list can have several elements (not only 2 as the example) and the number of elements can vary across the rows.

can anyone suggest how to easily achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I flattened the `mydf['WeirdField']` column so we could see just the values and column names, and don't have to worry about the lists in which they're contained. Next, you can use `itertools.groupby` to get all of the corresponding values and indices for each "F" column.

```
import itertools

# Must first sort the list by F column, or groupby won't work                  
flatter = sorted([list(x) + [idx] for idx, y in enumerate(mydf['WeirdField']) 
                  for x in y], key = lambda x: x[1]) 

# Find all of the values that will eventually go in each F column                
for key, group in itertools.groupby(flatter, lambda x: x[1]):
    list_of_vals = [(val, idx) for val, _, idx in group]

    # Add each value at the appropriate index and F column
    for val, idx in list_of_vals:
        mydf.loc[idx, key] = val
```

Yields this:

```
In [84]: mydf
Out[84]: 
  Field1 Field2              WeirdField   F1   F2   F3   F4   F5
0      A      1  [(xxx, F1), (yyy, F2)]  xxx  yyy  NaN  NaN  NaN
1      B      2  [(asd, F3), (bla, F4)]  NaN  NaN  asd  bla  NaN
2      C      3  [(123, F2), (www, F5)]  NaN  123  NaN  NaN  www
```

Comment: thanks, this is great. Loved how there is no hard coding of values or field names. I had only to change the enumerate to mydf['WeirdField'].iteritems() because I needed to keep the dataframe index.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

mydf = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'Field1' : ['A','B','C'],
        'Field2' : ['1','2','3'],
        'WeirdField' :[ 
                      [ ('xxx', 'F1'), ('yyy','F2'),('xyz','F6') ],
                      [ ('asd', 'F3'), ('bla','F4') ],
                      [ ('123', 'F2'), ('www','F5') ,('mno','F1') ]
                      ]
        })

print mydf.head()

# Create a new data frame with just field1 and field2

newdf = pd.DataFrame({'Field1' : ['A','B','C'],
        'Field2' : ['1','2','3'],
        })
# create a list of columns
column_names = []
for index, row in mydf.iterrows():
    for j in range( len(mydf['WeirdField'][index])):
        column_names.append( mydf['WeirdField'][index][j][1])

# Create a unique set of columns names
new_column_names = list(set(column_names))

# Add list of columns to the new dataframe and populate with None
for i,j in enumerate(new_column_names):
    newdf.insert(i+2,j,None)

# now add the elements into the columns
for index, row in mydf.iterrows():
    for j in range( len(mydf['WeirdField'][index])):
        newdf.set_value(index, [mydf['WeirdField'][index][j][1]], mydf['WeirdField'][index][j][0])

print newdf.head()
```

yields

```
  Field1 Field2    F1    F2    F3    F4    F5    F6
0      A      1   xxx   yyy  None  None  None   xyz
1      B      2  None  None   asd   bla  None  None
2      C      3   mno   123  None  None   www  None
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) solution after zipping through column values. This will work in any number of tuples in *WeirdField* assuming none of the F's repeat in same row as pivot will take max value:

```
data =[]
# APPEND TO LIST
for f1,f2,w in zip(mydf['Field1'].values, mydf['Field2'].values, mydf['WeirdField'].values):
    for i in w:
        data.append((f1, f2) + i)
# CAST LIST OF TUPLES TO DATAFRAME
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Field1', 'Field2', 'Value', 'Indicator'])

# PIVOT DATAFRAME
pvt = df.pivot_table(index=['Field1', 'Field2'], columns=['Indicator'],
                     values='Value', aggfunc='max', fill_value=np.nan).reset_index()
pvt.columns.name = None

#   Field1 Field2   F1   F2   F3   F4   F5
# 0      A      1  xxx  yyy  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 1      B      2  NaN  NaN  asd  bla  NaN
# 2      C      3  NaN  123  NaN  NaN  www
```